# nginx on vagrant keeps on dropping port

Tags: redirect, nginx, vagrant, virtualbox, http-status-code-301

so I have vagrant with port forwarding

here is vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 2048
        v.cpus = 4
  end

  config.berkshelf.enabled = true
  config.berkshelf.berksfile_path = "./Berksfile"
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2020

end
```

Here is nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;


  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;

  keepalive_requests 100;
  keepalive_timeout  65;


  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_vary off;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml text/javascript application/javascript application/json text/mathml;
  gzip_min_length  1000;
  gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";


  variables_hash_max_size 1024;
  variables_hash_bucket_size 64;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  types_hash_bucket_size 64;



  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

here is sites_enabled/default

```
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name  precise64;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

  root   /vagrant/site/www/public;
  index  index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  }
}
```

The issue is that everytime I go to http://localhost:8080/somedirectory on my browser, nginx ends up redirecting (301) to http://localhost/somedirectory

If I access a specific file, it doesn't do the redirect as expected

why is that happening and how can I prevent nginx from dropping the port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a redirect in your NGINX config so my guess is that it's coming from your PHP app.

Comment: well it happens for any directory even if there is no php script in it

Comment: The default in your try_files statement is to run the php script. NGINX might not be able to find the directory or have permissions, and defaulting to the php script. Its hard to say more without seeing your access logs.